# Algorithm to find and print simple cycle in complexity of O(n) on undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Given `graph G(V,E),` un-directed graph.

```
|E| = m, |V| = n
```

The graph's data structure is Adjacency list

How to find and print simple cycle (or print that there is no such cycle) in complexity of `O(n)`?
(If there is cycle the output should be the list of vertex that are part of the cycle.)

I know how to find cycle on complexity of `O(n)`, there is also gudies on the internet.
My problem is how to **print** it.

This is what I tried to do:

```
DFS-CheckCycle ( Graph G)
{
    p[] <- null //parent array
    foreach v in V
        Color[u] <- white

    foreach v in V
    {
        if (Color[u] = white) 
            Visit(u)
    }
}

Visit(Vertex u)
{
    bool Cycle <- false;
    Color[u] <- gray
    foreach v in Adj[u]
    {
        p[v] <- u
        if (Color[v] = white)
            Visit(v);
        else if (Color[v] = gray) 
        {
            Cycle <- true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!Cycle)
        print "No Cycle"
    else
        PrintCycle(v,u)
}



PrintCycle(Vertex v, Vertex u)
{
    if(v = u)
        print v;
    else
    {
        print v;
        PrintCycle(p[v], u);
    }
}
```

remember that it needs to be `O(n)`.
My PrintCycle function doesn't print all the vertexes.

I need some help how to print the vertexes of the cycle I found.

Comment: Google for "Floyd's algorithm" (but your coloring method could work just as well) BTW: in stead of a color, you could store the number of hops from the starting point (and maybe the node from where this node was visited)

Comment: I did't read your code , but if DFS is used in a proper way it should construct array stores (each node and its parent), use this array to reconstruct your path.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in strictly O(n) since all traversal algorithms I'm aware of are O(n+m).

Comment: @G.Bach I think he assumed that vertices count is greater than edges , so it's almost O(2n) = O(n). but as you said I also know it's O(n+m).

Comment: @wildplasser, Floyd's algorithm won't help me here. its complexity in the worst case is n^3

Comment: If I read your algorithm correct it will report A->B->A as a cycle (It could be considered a length=1 cycle) I think you should explicitely exclude the step back to the previous while iterating in Visit().

Comment: @mohaned If there's at least n edges there must be a cycle (because a maximal acyclic graph is a tree which has n-1 edges). This means you can discard all but the first n edges and the resulting graph will have a cycle iff the original graph did. Thus you don't need to worry about m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed two things which does not seem correct in your algorithm. Firstly, when you use your DFS walk, you should maintain the following invariant:

1. Unvisited vertices should be painted white; (you did that)
2. Visited vertices, for which `Visit()` hasn't ended yet, should be painted gray;
3. Visited vertices, for which `Visit()` has returned should be painted black(or color, other than gray or white).

The other thing I noticed, you don't assign parents for nodes correctly. In your `Visit()` method parents are assigned even if the vertex we want to visit on the next step is gray, i.e. already has a parent in DFS-tree.

So I would change your code accordingly:

```
DFS-CheckCycle ( Graph G)
{
    p[] <- null //parent array
    foreach v in V
        Color[v] <- white

    foreach u in V
    {
        if (Color[u] = white) {
            p[u] <- -1; // meaning it is a root of a DFS-tree of the DFS forest
            Visit(u)
        }
    }
}

Visit(Vertex u)
{
    bool Cycle <- false;
    Color[u] <- gray
    foreach v in Adj[u]
    {
        if (Color[v] = white) {
            p[v] <- u
            Visit(v);
        }
        else if (Color[v] = gray) 
        {
            Cycle <- true;
            break;
        }
    }
    Color[u] <- black; // once DFS for this vertex ends, assign its color to black

    if(!Cycle)
        print "No Cycle"
    else
        PrintCycle(v,u)
}



PrintCycle(Vertex v, Vertex u)
{
    if(v = u)
        print v;
    else
    {
        print v;
        PrintCycle(p[v], u);
    }
}
```

EDIT: It might be a good idea to turn your `PrintCycle` method into non-recursive one:

```
PrintCycle(Vertex v, Vertex u) 
{
    do {
        print u;
        u = p[u];
    } while (u != v);
}
```

Comment: Your non-recursive `PrintCycle` is **incorrect**. It will not print `v` even it is on the cycle (if `u==v` only then it will print `v`).

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive search, you can add a parameter that is a chain of ancestors all the way to the search root.  The cycle will consist of the current node and those in the chain ending at the gray node found to discover the cycle.

By chain I mean a lisp-style list: a pair consisting of a node and another pair, the final pair being null.

A more straightforward way is to search with an explicit stack rather than recursion.  The Nodes on the stack are all gray.  When you find a gray node indicating cycle, the cycle can be printed by working backward through the stack.

Comment: But there is a problem with the stack idea although I like it.
If in the begging I am passing over lonely vertex a and adding him to the stack.
When I will find a cycle I will print the stack but it will also print the lonely vertex and it is not good.
I need to print only the vertex in the cycle I found.

Comment: @EviatarG. I have no idea what you mean by lonely vertex.  If you find a cycle, the definition of cycle implies directly that the cycle _must_ be on the stack. If a vertex has an edge that connects the vertex to itself, that's still a cycle.

Comment: ok. so your suggestion is to add "Stack stack;" in the begging of DFS-CheckCycle and in the Visit function to add "stack.Push(v)" below the "if(Color[v] =white)" statement ?
and when I find a cycle just print it ?