# Print all verticies in graph's cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle

I've tried according to this [Algorithm to find and print simple cycle in complexity of O(n) on undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340898).
Did it in **C++** according to my tutor and following is my code:

```
int parent[1000] = {0};
int status[1000] = {0};
bool oriented = true;

#include ...

using namespace std;
array<list<int>, 1000 + 1> g;


void PrintCycle(int v, int u) {
    do {
        printf("%d",u);
        u = parent[u];
    } while (u != v);
}

bool DFS_cycle(int u) {
    status[u] = 1;
    for (int v:g[u]) {
        if (status[v] == 0) {
            parent[v] = u;
            DFS_cycle(v);
        }
        if (status[v] == 1 && v != parent[u]) {
            PrintCycle(v,u);
        }
    }
    status[u] = 2;
}


int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int N, u, v;
    cin >> N;
    while (cin >> u >> v) {
        g[u].push_back(v);
        g[v].push_back(u);
    }

    parent[1] = 1;
    DFS_cycle(1);
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work for the following input: (First line is the number of vertices. Vertices are numbered from 1. After that each line describes an edge.)

8

3  1

3  4

3  2

2  5

2  6

6  7

6  8

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the input. 

What I could understand is first int (here 8) is the number of vertices (I am assuming that vertices are numbered from 1...`N`).

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have used **C++** not **C**.

For the given input there is **no** cycle. It doesn't print any cycle either. So it **does** work for the given input.

However your code has **bug**. If we add another edge `(5,8)` a cycle is formed `(2 -> 5 -> 8 -> 6)`. But your code prints the cycle as `(6 -> 8 -> 5)`.

Check out my code for your bug :

```
void PrintCycle(int v, int u) {
    while(u != v)
    {
        printf("%d ",u); // You didn't give any space after %d
        // It could not be possible to differentitate between '1''2'
        // and '12'

        u = parent[u];
    }

    printf("%d \n", v);

}

bool DFS_cycle(int u) {

    status[u] = 1;
    for (int v:g[u]) {
        if (status[v] == 0) {
            parent[v] = u;
            DFS_cycle(v);
        }
        else if (status[v] == 1 && v != parent[u]) { // It should be 'else if' NOT 'if'
            PrintCycle(v,u);
            break;
        }
    }
    status[u] = 2;
}
```

And it is a good idea to `#define WHITE 0`, `#define GRAY 1` etc and then using `WHITE`, `GRAY` etc instead of using bare `1`, `2` etc.

Comment: Hmm, I knew It was C++ just a typeo.... But your code still doesn't work

Comment: @Rules, I am sorry to hear that my code doesn't work. 

Would you point out in which case my code fails?

Comment: 10
3 1
 3 4
  3 2
   2 5
    2 6
     6 7
      6 8
      5 9
      9 10 Nothing is outputed

Comment: @Rules, Thank you for giving an input.

First of all you have 8 vertices (if I could understand your input correctly). So vertices 9, 10 can **not** exist. And even if vertices 9, 10 exist, this graph does **not** have a cycle (at least I can't find any cycle after drawing it on paper. Would you mind finding me a cycle in the graph given by you?) . So **nothing** should be outputed.

Comment: Oh wow Really Thank you so much! Really I draw a graph correctly but entered it in a wrong way 7 8 and 4 5 edges were lost ... And such a stuoid person as I am even wants to get "alhoritms" exam passed)